# round vs hexagon

Tags: materials, structural-analysis, stresses

I want to make a durable lightweight container that maintains it's shape, I am aware that a hexagon shape has the best compression ratio, but does that translate into a stronger more robust structure?

I want to build a container that will be used to store refuse,soil, feed, fertilizer etc. The containers need to take a lot of abuse as currently the plastic round containers seem to not last at all.

Comment: What will this container contain? It is unclear what your criteria are, and therefore this question can't attract good answers as it is currently.

Answer (score 1):

A circle (cylinder or sphere) is the strongest shape for a given wall thickness for a tank, pressure vessel, or reducing localized wall deflection. A circle has the highest area to perimeter ratio. Without knowing more details, this is likely your best solution. This is why most containers are round.

A hexagon shape works well as internal trussing structure in sandwich structured composites. As a vessel it is stronger than a rectangular box of similar volume because the wall spans are shorter, but it will not be as strong as a circle for a given wall thickness.

Comment: Hexagon is basically a poor-mans circle that can also completely fill an area.  It's just a compromise between a low number of edges and an infinite number of edges.